# How to connect client (on VirtualBox) and server (on localhost)? I use CORBA and C++/Java

Tags: java, c++, connection, virtualbox, corba

I have a simple 'Hello world' `C++/Java` app with `CORBA`. Server is written in `C++`, client in `Java`. I use omniORBs `omniNames`, as name service.

I would like to run my `omniNames` and server on my `localhost` 
(Ubuntu) and run my client on Windows XP SP3 in VirtualBox installed on my localhost Ubuntu.

(I mean: on my localhost I have installed Ubuntu OS and in Ubuntu I installed VirtuaBox with Windows XP SP3 'inside'.)

I tried this:

1. I ran omniNames on my Ubuntu localhost, : `omniNames -start`
2. I ran my server, also on the same computer, localhost with Ubuntu OS:
   `./server -ORBInitRef
   NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService`
3. I checked my localhosts ip address on site: http://whatismyipaddress.com/ and
   wrote it down, which was, for example: x.x.x.x
4. Turned on Windows XP on VirtualBox, ran client: `java client -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::x.x.x.x:2809/NameService`

but got errors:

```
C:\Temp\java>java client -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc:212.106.19.209:2809/Na
meService
pač 10, 2012 3:51:17 PM com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL badA
ddress
WARNING: "IOP00110603: (BAD_PARAM) Bad host address in -ORBInitDef"
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 603  completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.NamingSystemException.insBadAddress(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.NamingSystemException.insBadAddress(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL.badAddress(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL.<init>(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.INSURLHandler.parseURL(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.operate(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.ORBInitRefResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown
 Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown
Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(Unknown
Source)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(Unknown
Source)
        at client.main(client.java:28)

C:\Temp\java>
```

Is it possible to connect client and server that way? How should I do this? I have only clients files on Windows XP - nothing more - no nameservice, no server files, just clients program.

Comment: You can use the commandline option -ORBtraceLevel 40 to see which IPs are used.

Comment: @tuergeist : I used it, thanks and I also checked `ifconfig`. If you can help more, please see comment to Ian Roberts' answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I checked my localhosts ip address on site: http://whatismyipaddress.com/ and wrote it down, which was, for example: x.x.x.x

This is very unlikely to be the right IP address to use.  How have you configured networking for your VirtualBox VM?  If you're using the default NAT networking then the guest can't talk to the host, so instead you need to configure a "host-only" network, and then use the IP address of the host side of this network (which you should be able to find using `ifconfig` on the Ubuntu host, look for the `vboxnet` interface) when telling the client where to find the ORB.  You may also find you need to add firewall rules on the host machine to permit incoming connections on the virtual interface.

Note that you can have more than one network interface configured for the same VM, so if the VM needs access to the internet as well as to the ORB then it's perfectly OK to set it up with two interfaces, one NAT and the other host-only.

Comment: thank you so much! It worked but not at all. When I switched my internet connection in VirtualBox to `bridget` and chose `eth0` and had my Internet connected - it was fine. But with the same seetings when I plugged off my internet cable, it didnt want to work :( Its quite a problem because I need to show this app in my class to my teacher and other students but we dont have the internet in our class... Is it possible to connect client and server without internet connected?

Comment: I forgot: when I tried to use `host-only` option, VirtualBox said 'wrong settings' and didnt let me to choose this option :/

Comment: Host-only is definitely the option you need.  As this is now a VirtualBox configuration issue rather than a programming one you'll probably get a better response if you ask on superuser rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: you were right of course :) But the new issue came out - if you find some time will you be able to see my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860512/connectionerror-client-on-virtualbox-and-server-on-localhost-i-use-host? Thanks in advance, you helped a lot! :)