# ConnectionError [client (on VirtualBox) and server (on localhost)] - I use host-only setting on VM

Tags: java, c++, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, corba

I have a simple calc C++/Java app with CORBA. Server is written in C++, client in Java. I use omniORBs omniNames, as name service.

I would like to run my omniNames and server on my localhost (Ubuntu) and run my client on Windows XP SP3 in VirtualBox installed on my localhost Ubuntu.

(I mean: on my localhost I have installed Ubuntu OS and in Ubuntu I installed VirtuaBox with Windows XP SP3 'inside'.)

I finally did it and set `host-only` optinon in VirtualBox with help from this: https://superuser.com/questions/429405/how-can-i-get-virtualbox-to-run-with-a-hosts-only-adapter topic. Now I have some other problem. My client finally see my server and even can connect to it and send him a message but it has problems with receiving an answer from server: (this time my app is a simple calc):

```
C:\Temp\java>java client -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::192.168.56.1:2809/NameService  Choose:
1.Add
2.Sub
3.Mul
4.Div
> 3 
> Pass number:
> 2
> Pass number:
> 4 
> pač 12, 2012 3:36:58 PM  com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectio nImpl <init> WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType:  IIOP_CLEAR
_TEXT; hostname: 127.0.0.1; port: 41431" org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
        at  com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(U nknown Source)
        at  com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(U nknown Source)
        at  com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>( Unknown Source)
        at  com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>( Unknown Source)
        at  com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.create Connection(Unknown Source)
        at  com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.begin Request(Unknown Source)
        at  com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(Unknow n Source)
        at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(Unknown Source)
        at _CalcStub.mul(_CalcStub.java:64)
        at client.main(client.java:65) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
        at  com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket (Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more



C:\Temp\java>
```

Where 192.168.56.1 is a VirtualBox host-only ip address. Please help:) In the example I posted here, the answer from server should be 8 (because as we all know 2*4 = 8;)

OK friends, sorry for bothering all of you:) I found the answer: I added those lines to my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
allow-hotplug eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Cheerz:D

Comment: Have you checked that you can ping your VM from your host OS? If you can't, then I recommend you to use the [Bridged Networking](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#idp17444608), this will allow that your VM will behave as a physical machine in your LAN.

Comment: I'm interested in the caller code, i.e., client.java line 65

Comment: @tuergeist: Here you go: `double res = calc.mul(num1, num2); System.out.println("Result: "+res);` those are line 64 and 65 (System.out. ... is line 65) :)

Comment: @yak and calc is the remote object und mul is the first call to it? more code would be helpful

Comment: by the way: is your servant code properly registered at your naming service? It seems that your sevant ORB uses the local host loopback ip instead of its public ip. Use -ORBtraceLevel 40 for the server as an commandline argument to see which ip is detected and used.